# openshift fails to deploy jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

When I try to deploy jenkins-ephemeral on openshift 1.5, it fails with the following error message

```
error: couldn't get deployment jenkins-3: Get https://172.30.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/projectname/replicationcontrollers/jenkins-3: dial tcp 172.30.0.1:443: getsockopt: network is unreachable
```

I have services enabled

```
oc get services
NAME           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
jenkins        172.30.86.254    <none>        80/TCP      59m
jenkins-jnlp   172.30.132.179   <none>        50000/TCP   59m
```

but from the node I can't telnet to port 80 of 172.30.86.254

```
telnet: connect to address 172.30.86.254: Connection refused
```

but the 443 port of the same machine is reachable.

Comment: what does ```oc status -v``` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be [a proxy issue](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/14742) in your config. It is solved by [setting NO_PROXY](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/http_proxies.html#configuring-no-proxy) as follows:

> Edit the proxy environment variables in the OpenShift Origin control files. Ensure all of the files in the cluster are correct.

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://<user>:<password>@<ip_addr>:<port>/
HTTPS_PROXY=https://<user>:<password>@<ip_addr>:<port>/
NO_PROXY=master.hostname.example.com,10.1.0.0/16,172.30.0.0/16
```

> Supports host names and [CIDRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). Must include the [SDN network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_networking) and service IP ranges 10.1.0.0/16,172.30.0.0/16 by default.